# Searching a list to make different series, then plotting their corresponding values

Tags: vba, excel, plot, excel-2013

Let me start out by saying I am new to both this site and VBA (I took a crash course in high school, so I get basic coding jargon). I have been looking for several days now to find the code that would work to do what I need, but I haven't found anything.

Basically I have a bunch of sand samples that have been sieved. Every sample gets its own sheet. From here, I have a Master Summary Sheet that collects the data I need to plot from these other sheets and puts it into a table. It also finds the type of sample and the date of the test. There are 6 different types of sample (so far).

Also, I need the summary table to be plotted with date on the x-axis, and percent on the y-axis. I need each sample type to have its own series. I have gotten to where I have all 6 series divided correctly (though I am sure the code is awfully inefficient) but I can't figure out how to get the value from the column next to the sample type to be plotted. In other words, everything is stuck at a value of "0" because it is sorting it by string right now.

I've put my code and a text version of my excel sheet below. I appreciate any help you can give me!

```
'Sheet           Date       Type    Sieve #40
'Truck 47533    4/15/2016   Truck       55%
'Truck 47272    4/4/2016    Truck       55%
'47272          4/4/2016    CoA         48%
'Basement 4-4   4/4/2016    Basement    55%
'Bin2 4-4       4/4/2016    Bin2        55%
'Bin1 4-4       4/4/2016    Bin1        55%
'Hopper 4-4     4/4/2016    Hopper      57%
'Basement 4-1   4/1/2016    Basement    58%
'Bin2 4-1       4/1/2016    Bin2        54%
'Bin1 4-1       4/1/2016    Bin1        58%
'Hopper 4-1     4/1/2016    Hopper      56%
'Truck 46892    4/1/2016    Truck       56%
'46892          4/1/2016    CoA         47%
'Basement 3-24  3/24/2016   Basement    55%
'Bin2 3-24      3/24/2016   Bin2        57%
'Bin1 3-24      3/24/2016   Bin1        61%
'Hopper 3-24    3/24/2016   Hopper      50%    

Sub ChartingSub()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Truck As Range
Dim Hopper As Range
Dim Bin1 As Range
Dim Bin2 As Range
Dim Basement As Range
Dim coa As Range
Dim NewSand As Range
Dim ShName As String
Dim dates As Range

    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name
    End With

With ActiveSheet
    Set dates = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
End With

    For Each c In Rng1
        If c.Value = "Truck" Then
            If Not Truck Is Nothing Then
                Set Truck = Union(Truck, c)
            Else
                Set Truck = c
            End If

         ElseIf c.Value = "Hopper" Then
            If Not Hopper Is Nothing Then
                Set Hopper = Union(Hopper, c)
            Else
                Set Hopper = c
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value = "Bin1" Then
            If Not Bin1 Is Nothing Then
                Set Bin1 = Union(Bin1, c)
            Else
                Set Bin1 = c
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value = "Bin2" Then
            If Not Bin2 Is Nothing Then
                Set Bin2 = Union(Bin2, c)
            Else
                Set Bin2 = c
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value = "Basement" Then
            If Not Basement Is Nothing Then
                Set Basement = Union(Basement, c)
            Else
                Set Basement = c
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value = "CoA" Then
            If Not coa Is Nothing Then
                Set coa = Union(coa, c)
            Else
                Set coa = c
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value = "NewSand" Then
            If Not NewSand Is Nothing Then
                Set NewSand = Union(NewSand, c)
            Else
                Set NewSand = c
            End If
        End If
    Next

Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set cht = cht.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName)
    With cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Sieve #40 Trend"
    End With

Dim t As Series
Set t = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With t
    .Values = Truck
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "Truck"
End With

Dim h As Series
Set h = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With h
    .Values = Hopper
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "Hopper"
End With

Dim b As Series
Set b = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With b
    .Values = Basement
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "Basement Reclaim"
End With

Dim b1 As Series
Set b1 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With b1
    .Values = Bin1
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "Bin1"
End With

Dim b2 As Series
Set b2 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With b2
    .Values = Bin2
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "Bin2"
End With

Dim cert As Series
Set cert = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With cert
    .Values = coa
    .XValues = dates
    .Name = "CoA"
End With

'Dim ns As Series
'Set ns = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
'With ns
    '.Values = NewSand
    '.XValues = dates
    '.Name = "New Resin Sand"
'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the sheet looks like? It's hard to visualize.

Comment: I can't post a picture of it right now (image sites blocked at work), but at the top of the coding block is a text version of my sheet. The four headings are "Sheet" "Date" "Type" and "Sieve #40". The current code spits out a plot of dates and percent (x-axis and y-axis) and all 6 series are at in a line at 0%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a plot where X is date, Y is percent, and "Z" is the type. Then you need to do the following:

1. In Excel you need to create each series individually - so if you have say 5 types then you need to plot each one separately.
2. The easiest way to do that is to sort by type, loop over all the rows, and figure out the boundaries so type 1 maybe rows 2-11, type 2 12-15, etc.
3. Then you can plot each series

Something like this - where the start and end is found using above:

```
For a = 1 To lastrow
    With ActiveChart 
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries 
                .XValues = Sheets(strName).Range("E" & startx & ":E" & endx)
                .Values = Sheets(strName).Range("E" & starty & ":E" & endy)
                .Name = strName 
            End With 
        End If 
    End With 
Next a
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without sorting? I have other people continually adding data to this list, and the type is random. The way I have the code currently gets me the 6 different series based on Column C, but it does not give any corresponding numerical values to them (which are in Column D). So row 1, 2, and 12 are type "Truck" and the values that need to be plotted in the "Truck" series are 55%, 55%, and 56% from rows 1, 2, and 12, in the "Sieve #40" column.

Comment: Sure. Just copy the worksheet and plot off that duplicate sorted worksheet. You can even hide the worksheet if you want and on one will know the difference.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is that I would like it to be as automated as possible. I want them to enter their data, click on the button in the summary sheet, and the macro will run and give them a trend plot. If I have to copy and sort the data prior to running the program each time, then it really doesn't help me much.

Comment: You can copy and sort using VBA...